# Do batches need to be sequential in Transformer traning?

Tags: transformer, pytorch

When training a transformer model (I'm using nn.TransformerEncoder from pytorch) is it better to use sequential batches (for example, three sequences `[[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]]` where next sequence continues where the previous ended)?

Or can I use non-sequential or randomly picked sequences from my dataset (for example, here are three randomly picked sequences `[[1,2,3,4], [56, 57, 58, 59], [22, 23, 24, 25]]`)?

I can make a test myself, but I was just wondering if that's already known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each sample in each batch is processed separately. Each batch in turn is handled separately. Having consistency between batches is not going to improve the convergence of your model.

If any, it might result in a less generalized model because your data is [not shuffled enough](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/24511/why-should-the-data-be-shuffled-for-machine-learning-tasks).